# Internal server error while getting LinkedIn API Access token

Tags: linkedin-api

We are migrating to Community Management API, we created a new app and follow this guideline
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/community-management-api-migration-guide?view=li-lms-2023-06

We need to get 3 permissions:
rw_organization_admin
w_organization_social_feed
r_organization_social_feed

To get code, we use this link

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=Client_Id}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&state=&scope=rw_organization_admin%20w_organization_social_feed%20r_organization_social_feed
```

We succsessfully get the code, but when we try to get token we get internal server error from linkedin API.
We noticed that if we request any 2 of these 3 permissions we get token successfully.
So when we use any of these scope parameters below to get code, we can successfully get token from that code:

```
scope=rw_organization_admin%20w_organization_social_feed
```

```
scope=rw_organization_admin%20r_organization_social_feed
```

```
scope=w_organization_social_feed%20r_organization_social_feed
```

but if we use all 3 scopes it fails

```
scope=rw_organization_admin%20w_organization_social_feed%20r_organization_social_feed
```

How can we fix this issue?